# How to make a scatterplot based upon certain criteria using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

For learning how to use d3.js, I was trying to use titanic dataset for learning available on kaggle.

I am trying to achieve the objective:

1. Make a scatterplot of age vs fare with age in x axis and fare in y axis
2. Use the sex column to have male as square and female as circles in the scatterplot
3. Have opacity to indicate the condition - survived or not survived.

I have used the following code:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 600])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    .attr("r", 1.5)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

The condition I want to implement is:

```
if(d.sex == "female"){
    return d3.symbolCircle;
} else if (d.sex == "male"){
    return d3.symbolSquare;
}
```

But, being absolute new to the syntax, I am not understanding how. Also, How to have two colors for the 3rd objective of indicating survivor vs dead.

Can anyone help me please. I really thank you in advance.

In case you do not have the dataset, it can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to look at your data. Your properties are all uppercase, and reading a CSV file always means that you need to parse your rows: numbers and dates are still strings, you need to cast them as such:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(rawData) {
  // All values are strings here, so we need to parse some of them.
  // You can do that using `+x` or `Number(x)`, where `x = "123"`
  const data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      age: Number(d.Age),
      // cabin: d.Cabin,
      // embarked: e.Embarked,
      fare: Number(d.Fare),
      // name: d.Name,
      // parch: Number(d.Parch),
      // passengerId: Number(d.PassengerId)
      // pclass: Number(Pclass),
      sex: d.Sex,
      // sibSp: Number(d.SibSp),
      survived: d.Survived === "1"
      // ticket: d.Ticket,
    };
  });

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 600])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(d.age);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.fare);
    })
    .attr("r", 1.5)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Secondly, circles can only be circles. To draw both squares and circles, you'll need to use `<path>`. Your `d3.symbol*` were correct, but you need to access their `.draw()` function. `d3.path` is a generator to easily draw the `d` attribute of a path:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(rawData) {
  // All values are strings here, so we need to parse some of them.
  // You can do that using `+x` or `Number(x)`, where `x = "123"`
  const data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      age: Number(d.Age),
      // cabin: d.Cabin,
      // embarked: e.Embarked,
      fare: Number(d.Fare),
      // name: d.Name,
      // parch: Number(d.Parch),
      // passengerId: Number(d.PassengerId)
      // pclass: Number(Pclass),
      sex: d.Sex,
      // sibSp: Number(d.SibSp),
      survived: d.Survived === "1"
      // ticket: d.Ticket,
    };
  });

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 600])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [x(d.age), y(d.fare)] + ")";
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      const path = d3.path();
      const shape = d.sex == "female" ? d3.symbolCircle : d3.symbolSquare;
      shape.draw(path, 8);
      return path.toString();
    })
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

(As an aside, you also could have drawn `rect`s for both, but given the female ones rounded corners with the [`rx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect) attribute).

Finally, you can use a colour scale for fill, with `d3.scaleOrdinal`, but if you have only two colours and don't use it to colour multiple things (like a line chart *and* a legend), just use an if statement:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", function(rawData) {
  // All values are strings here, so we need to parse some of them.
  // You can do that using `+x` or `Number(x)`, where `x = "123"`
  const data = rawData.map(function(d) {
    return {
      age: Number(d.Age),
      // cabin: d.Cabin,
      // embarked: e.Embarked,
      fare: Number(d.Fare),
      // name: d.Name,
      // parch: Number(d.Parch),
      // passengerId: Number(d.PassengerId)
      // pclass: Number(Pclass),
      sex: d.Sex,
      // sibSp: Number(d.SibSp),
      survived: d.Survived === "1"
      // ticket: d.Ticket,
    };
  });

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 600])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [x(d.age), y(d.fare)] + ")";
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      const path = d3.path();
      const shape = d.sex == "female" ? d3.symbolCircle : d3.symbolSquare;
      shape.draw(path, 8);
      return path.toString();
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.survived ? "#69b3a2" : "#ddd";
    })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wanted to ask one more thing: in style, we set "fill" for color, but I read and found that opacity is different from coloring. If we want to replace fill with opacity, can we continue with the same logic?

Comment: Yes, you can use *any* attribute. For opacity, you need to return a number between 0 and 1. In SVG, you have`opacity`, but also the more specific `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity`. Have a look at which you need

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, opacity concept is like probability having value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes, 0 is a piece of glass, 1 is a brick wall

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing in SVG is that a `<rect>` with the `rx` and `ry` attributes equal to half its width or height (those being the same, of course) becomes effectively a circle.

So, supposing you have

```
var diameter = 3;
```

All you need is:

```
.attr("rx", function(d) {
  return d.Sex === "male" ? 0 : diameter / 2
})
.attr("ry", function(d) {
  return d.Sex === "male" ? 0 : diameter / 2
})
```

And, of course, subtract the `x` and `y` positions by half the diameter (i.e., the radius).

That seems like a hack, but the advantage of that approach is that it's quite easy to transition between the square and the "circle" by just changing the rx/ry values (one can transition paths, but that's a bit more complicated). Have a look at this transition, with an exaggerated radius and a clipped domain:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 660 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var diameter = 12;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/michhar/2dfd2de0d4f8727f873422c5d959fff5/raw/fa71405126017e6a37bea592440b4bee94bf7b9e/titanic.csv", row, function(data) {

  // Add X axis
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 80])
    .range([0, width]);
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add Y axis
  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 300])
    .range([height, 0]);
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  // Add dots
  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x(d.Age) - diameter / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.Fare) - diameter / 2;
    })
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("rx", function(d) {
      return d.Sex === "male" ? 0 : diameter / 2
    })
    .attr("ry", function(d) {
      return d.Sex === "male" ? 0 : diameter / 2
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return +d.Survived ? "#69b3a2" : "tan"
    });

})

function row(d) {
  d.Age = +d.Age;
  d.Fare = +d.Fare;
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wanted to ask one more thing: in style, we set "fill" for color, but I read and found that opacity is different from coloring. If we want to replace fill with opacity, can we continue with the same logic if we use the same condition of changing opacity according to survived or not?

Comment: @KC yes, you can.